# Is a parameter name neccesary for virtual method definition in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```cpp
virtual bool myFunction(const Waypoints& /*waypoints*/) {
    return false;
}
```

For my understanding, `virtual` function is for late / dynamic binding. `bool` is the return type. `const Waypoint&` is a constant reference. When it is used to formal parameters, it avoids value copy and forbids being changed by the function.

Now, my question is, shall we need a variable name for the formal parameter of this function somehow? I mean, `/*waypoints*/` are simply comments, right? Where are the formal parameters then?

Comment: The parameter is unnamed. C++ allows to omit formal parameter names if they are not used in the function body.

Comment: you are not using the parameter. It wouldn't matter if you are having in the parameter name in the function definition or not. You'll anyhow pass the parameter when you are calling the function

Comment: The argument's name is only meaningful for the implementation of the function. At the callsite, all you can see is `ptr->myFunction(something)`. The fact that the argument is called "waypoint" is irrelevant, and not part of the function's signature.

Comment: Many (busybody) compilers will give a warning if an argument to a function is not used in that function. Leaving out the name usually suppresses that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has one formal parameter of type `const Waypoints&`. It is unnamed, because it is not used in the method body. This might make sense, because other implementations of the same method might use it (note that the method is virtual). Whether the name of the parameter `/*waypoints*/` is commented out, left there or removed altogether is a matter of taste. Some compilers issue a warning when a formal parameter (that does have a name) is not used in the method body, so this might be the reason it was commented out.

Answer (score 0):

A *declaration* of a function (member or free) never needs names for parameters (although they can be useful for the reader). A *definition* of a function only needs names for parameters that are used in the body of the function. You can have different names in different declarations, they are ignored.

> Where are the formal parameters then?

There is an parameter of type `const Waypoints&`. It is unnamed in the definition, which is fine because it is unused.